# Does use of vue.js make use of jQuery obsolete?

Tags: jquery, vue.js

Can any experienced vue js developer tell me, will use of vue js make use of jQuery library obsolete ???

Answer (score 1):

Google knows the [answer](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin/):

**The problem with using jQuery and Vue together**

*Why is doing this potentially hazardous?*

> Vue is a jealous library in the sense that you must let it completely
>   own the patch of DOM that you give it (defined by what you pass to
>   el). If jQuery makes a change to an element that Vue is managing, say,
>   adds a class to something, Vue won’t be aware of the change and is
>   going to go right ahead and overwrite it in the next update cycle.